# Linux Kernel module Remote Debugging with GDB + KGDB, Remote 'g' packet reply is too long

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-modules, debugging, gdb, kgdb

I am trying to remotely debug Linux Kernel and I am having issues.

My setup:

- Target machine with Ubnutu Linux with my custom kernel 4.3 which I built with debugging information and KGDB.
- Development machine with Windows and Cygwin on it.

I connected the machines with Serial port on the Linux side and USB on the Development machine side.
On target machine:
I loaded my module X with insmod,

```
>cat /sys/module/X/sections/.text
0xffffffffc046e000 
>cat /sys/module/X/sections/.bss
0xffffffffc04708c0 
>cat /sys/module/X/sections/.data
0xffffffffc0470000
```

I read that I'm supposed to start kernel with "some parameters" but I don't really understand how to do it in Ubuntu so I did this:

```
>echo "ttyS0,115200 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
```

Also tried just this:

```
echo ttyS0 > /sys/module/kgdboc/parameters/kgdboc
```

And then

```
>echo g > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

At this point the Linux machine froze, which is good. (waiting for gdb)
On the Windows machine I opened cygwin,
I put the vmlinux and X.o files in the root directory, as well as the source code in the right place.
Then I ran

```
gdb ./vmlinux - b 115200
(gdb) add-symbol-file byt_adsp21479.o 0xffffffffc046e000 -s .bss 0xffffffffc04708c0 -s .data 0xffffffffc0470000
(gdb) set architecture i386:x86-64:intel
```

Then I set some break points in my kernel module and ran

```
(gdb) target remote /dev/ttyS7 which is COM8
```

that worked and after typing

```
(gdb) continue
```

The linux machine unfroze,
However when I ran an operation on my Linux machine that should trigger a break point, I got this message on the Development machine:

```
[New Thread 3264]
Ignoring packet error, continuing...
Remote 'g' packet reply is too long: 0840000000000000000e00080847c0ffffffff000100c0000000000300000000000000bc3b63360088ffff0000000000000000a03b63360088ffff983b63360088ffff000063360088ffff2f944e2fbd3b000020c00a360088ffff000000000000000000000000000000000300000000000000000000000000000000ccd7ceff7f0000ede146c0ffffffff4602000010000000180000000000000000000000
```

The weirdest is that once, I was able to step into 2 functions but then I got the same error message.
What can be the issues?

Just FYI I already throught of abandoning debugging through serial port, and trying through ethernet,
So I went here http://sysprogs.com/VisualKernel/kgdboe/tutorial/
And downloaded and built kgboe, but when I tried to run insmod kgdboe.ko I got an error:

```
insmod: Error: could not insert module kgdboe.ko : Unknown symbol module
```

and when I run dmesg
I see

```
kgdboe: Unknown symbol set_memory_rw (err 0)
```

With the setup I have, can anyone please help me find a way to debug my kernel module please.
Thank you!

Comment: Debugging kernel from windows? Get a second Linux instead.

Comment: Can you please explain how do you deduct from the error message that the problem is Windows? I am using Cygwin on Windows. And the guys that SysProgs that created VisualKernel for Visual Studio are also using Windows.

Comment: Judging by address lengths and `set architecture` command, I see you're debugging a x86_64 kernel. Just a first thought - Windows use LLP64 and Linux use LP64.

Comment: That's interesting. I will try on my Mac ( I don't have another Linux machine unfortunately)

Comment: If you have a decent CPU with enough RAM and CPU has virtualization assistance, you can install second Linux into a VM such as VirtualBox and try from there.